# Nodejs script fails importing dependency inside docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a small nodejs script which runs fine locally. I moved it to an ubuntu based dockerfile, in which I install npm and then run the script. Running the image in the container fails because of an `SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier` for the first import in the nodejs script.

Here's the first line of my nodejs script:

```
// bla.js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
#Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN mkdir -p buildspace
COPY . buildspace/
WORKDIR ./buildspace

# install npm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs \
    npm    

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

CMD ["node", "bla.js"]
```

Building the image is successful. When I then try to run the image using `docker run image_name`, I get the following error:

```
/buildspace/bla.js:1
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
       ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
...
```

Running locally `npm ci` and `node bla.js` works like a charm. What am I doing wrong with the Dockerfile?

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` file that excludes the host's `node_modules` directory?  You `COPY` the application in twice, not specifically a problem but it's wasteful; I'd delete the two lines before `WORKDIR`.

Comment: Yes, I have the `node_modules` directory listed in `.gitignore`. Neither excluding it nor removing the unneeded two lines solved the problem.